# How to access variables of the 'main' SWF from a loaded SWF by SWFLoader?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm working on a website built in Flex, but the SWF file after compiling is very large. The websites has multiple pages.

So I thought to create a new MXML project for every new page and load it with SWFLoader.
I've found this example:

```
public function extSwfLoaded(evt:Event):void {
    var sysmgr:SystemManager = (extSwf.content as SystemManager);
    sysmgr.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void {
        var sysmgr:SystemManager = (event.currentTarget as SystemManager);
        var swfApp:Application = (sysmgr.application as Application);
    }
});

public function gotoPage(page:String):void {
    extSwf.addEventListener(Event.INIT, extSwfLoaded);

    var now:Date = new Date();

    switch(page) {
        case "register":
            openedPage = "register";
            extSwf.load('modules/register.swf?anticache=' + now.getTime());
            break;
    }
}
```

And in the MXML:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="extSwf" complete="extSwfLoaded(event)" width="100%" />

<s:Label text="Register" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="gotoPage('register')" />
```

This works perfect. The content of modules/register.swf is showed at the place of the *extSwf* SWFLoader.

**But**: I've no idea how to interact with the 'main' SWF and the loaded SWF file.

I have some global variables that I want to send to every loaded SWF file
(and some variables that I want to send from the loaded SWF file to the 'main' SWF file).

A website said that I can send these variables by loading *modules/register.swf?var1=hi&var2=hello*, but someone who can see the HTTP headers (for example with *Live HTTP Headers* in Firefox) can see all these variables.

So, is it possible to load a SWF file and send them some variables? And when I have a new global variable, I don't have to open and edit and recompile every MXML project?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems to me you should be able, in the swfs for each page, to have a method like `initWithWrapper(handleToWrapper:ClassNameOfWrapper)`, that your the wrapper swf calls once the swf to be loaded finishes loading. Once that link is established, they can talk to each other. Your `ClassNameOfWrapper` class would have to expose methods that the child swf could interact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can show the variables of my 'main' MXML.

```
import mx.controls.Alert; 
import mx.core.FlexGlobals; 

Alert.show(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myvar);
```

And for using public functions:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myFunction();
```

I just needed the right keywords (*top level application*) to search for it on the internet.